# Dismiss ProgressDialog after WebView has shown

Tags: android, webview

How can I use ProgressDialog to wait while WebView is loading?

Sometimes myText has a huge text and some old devices can't load WebView fast. I want to show ProgressDialog while WebView is loading and when it's already shown I want to dismiss the ProgressDialog.

I have:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
dialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
dialog.setIndeterminate(true) ;
dialog.show();

String myText = "some text";
WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", myText, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");

dialog.dismiss();
```

It doesn't show any ProgressDialog.

If I don't use dismiss, I always see my ProgressDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AsyncTask`.

```
 // ..onCreate code come here...


 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
     bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               new LongOperation().execute(); // here calling LongOperation class to do `AsyncTask`.
            }

        });

 private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog dialog; 

     @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

     dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.class);
     dialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
     dialog.setIndeterminate(true) ;
     dialog.show();
     }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

     // background operation comes here..

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

       // close progressDialog here by calling
         dialog.dismiss();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I put my WebView in doInBackground. But i have this error: A WebView method was called on thread 'AsyncTask #2'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. How should I organize WebView?

Comment: I played with your example and it works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your current Java class which contains web view..

```
  private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if(dialog.isShowing() && dialog != null) {

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);


        if(!dialog.isShowing() && dialog != null) {

            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }


}
```

And set this

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

below you initialized your webview

Comment: How to use it for loadDataWithBaseURL("", myText, "text/html", "UTF-8", ""); ?

Comment: what are you doing in loadDataWithBaseURL("", myText, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");

Comment: String myText = "some text". By myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL() i load myText in WebView. Look at code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

just try this,

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            progDailog.show();
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url)
        {
            progDailog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't work, i want to use loadDataWithBaseURL("", myText, "text/html", "UTF-8", ""); But a method shouldOverrideUrlLoading doesn't work.